# what is different between entityset with objectset

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity

Can anyone tell me what is different between EntitySet and ObjectSet in EntityFramework ?

thanx for your guidances

Answer (score 2):

Your question is answered very nicely here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/c76d72c0-951c-4033-b75f-fc84f735826e

Hope that helps.